# Generating reports in activiti-5.19

Tags: report, activiti

I am using activiti-5.19. Activiti admin dashboard have a tab called report. I want to generate reports in activiti 5.19. How to generate reports in activiti 5.19. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With JDK 8 you must load the *mozilla_compat.js* compatibility script. See [JDK 8 Scripting guide - Importing Java Packages and Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#A1147207)

For instance, the demo report [employeeProductivity.bpmn20.xml](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-webapp-explorer2/src/main/resources/org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/reports/employeeProductivity.bpmn20.xml) shoud be modified as follows.

```
// Load compatibility script
load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");

importPackage(java.sql);
importPackage(java.lang);
importPackage(java.util);
importPackage(org.activiti.explorer.reporting);

var reportData = {
    "title": "My Report",
    "datasets": [
        {
            "type": "lineChart",
            "description": "My first chart",
            "xaxis": "Category",
            "yaxis": "Total sales",
            "data":
                    {"2010": 50, "2011": 33, "2012": 17, "2013": 87}
        }
    ]
};
execution.setVariable("reportData", new java.lang.String(JSON.stringify(reportData)).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

You can also use *JavaImporter* instead of *importPackage* as an alternative, in which case the the demo report [employeeProductivity.bpmn20.xml](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-webapp-explorer2/src/main/resources/org/activiti/explorer/demo/process/reports/employeeProductivity.bpmn20.xml) shoud be modified as follows

```
// Create a JavaImporter object with specified packages and classes to import
var imports = new JavaImporter(java.sql, java.lang, java.util, org.activiti.explorer.reporting);

// Pass the JavaImporter object to the "with" statement and access the classes
// from the imported packages by their simple names within the statement's body
with (imports) {
    var reportData = {
        "title": "My Report",
        "datasets": [
            {
                "type": "lineChart",
                "description": "My first chart",
                "xaxis": "Category",
                "yaxis": "Total sales",
                "data":
                        {"2010": 50, "2011": 33, "2012": 17, "2013": 87}
            }
        ]
    };
}
execution.setVariable("reportData", new java.lang.String(JSON.stringify(reportData)).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```